# CodePipeline: CodeDeploy reports "BundleType must be either YAML or JSON"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

[image: CodeDeploy reports "BundleType must be either YAML or JSON"]

[image: appspec.yml is in the root dir of CodeCommit]

buildspec.yml:

```html
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Compiling the Python code...
      - python HelloWorld_tst.py
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - HelloWorld.py
    - appspec.yml
  discard-paths: yes
```

appspec.yml

```js
version: 0.0
Resources:
    - autovisionfunction:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
            Name: "autovisionfunction"
            Alias: "staging"
            CurrentVersion: "1"
            TargetVersion: "2"
```

Seems while in CodePipeline can't find appspec.yml

I have downloaded artefact zip from S3 bucket, it has appspec.yml inside.

[image]

What do I miss?

Thank you

Olya

Comment: Are you sure the file extension has to be `.yml`? For over 12 years the [officially recommended extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files has been `.yaml`

Comment: I tried all possible formats and extensions, issues still remains
`appspec.json
appspec.yaml
appspec.yml
buildspec.yml
HelloWorld_tst.py
HelloWorld.py`

Answer (score 18):

I've currently been struggling with the same issue.

After some digging, I've found that it looks to be a limitation of linking the two services (codebuild and codedeploy) via codepipelines

Currently codebuild only supports ZIP/TAR/TGZ as the bundletypes (outputs) which codedeploy doesnt support

similar thread with an AWS response 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=864336

A work around is to trigger the codedeploy via the codebuild::project buildspec. Example below

```
export REVISION="revisionType=S3,s3Location{bucket=$BUCKET_DEPLOYMENTS,key=$CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID/appspec.yml,bundleType=YAML}"

aws deploy create-deployment \
    --application-name=$APPLICATION_NAME \
    --deployment-group-name=$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME \ 
    --revision=$REVISION \
    --deployment-config-name='CodeDeployDefault.LambdaCanary10Percent30Minutes'
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas on how to work out the limitation

Regards,

Comment: still relevant in Nov 2020 as they've still not fixed this. Thanks a lot, this was exactly what was needed.

Comment: still relevant in 2021 as they've still not fixed this.

Comment: still not work in 2023

Comment: you can using github action to deploy lambda, it works! https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-lambda-deploy